# Why is flying saucer always printing PDF on A4 paper?

Tags: pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I'm trying to save an html document to PDF using flyingsaucer but the generated document always ends up having an A4 dimension when I look at the Document Properties from Adobe Reader (Page Size: 8.26 x 11.69 in).

I did read the documentation and I'm passing the css @page {size: letter;} style. And while it does have an effect on the output, the page size always remains 8.26 x 11.69 in Adobe Reader. For example, if I set the page size to legal, my PDF is still the size of a A4 but the top of the document is missing as if it had fell off the "paper".

I'm not sure if the problem falls on the itext side or the flying saucer side. I was using a fairly old version so my first step was to upgrade to the latest 9.1.6 version of flying saucer. I also moved from itext 2.0.8 to openPDF 1.0.1 but I'm still getting the same behavior.

I also traced in the debugger up to the com.lowagie.text.Document creation in ITextRenderer and at this point the document size passed is correct. That makes me think that the issue might be in openPDF / iText but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I made a quick test using flyingsaucer 9.1.1 and it works for me. For `size:letter`, the generated PDF is 21,59 × 27,94 cm, which is correct (I'm in Europe, I don't have the value in inches). How do you pass the `@page` declaration ?

Comment: Thanks for testing @obourgain. I have added `<style type="text/css">
  @page { size: letter; } </style>` in the `<head>` section of my html document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the PDF generation was correctly using the @page size declaration and the problem was occurring later in our software. What I had not noticed is that after the generation of the PDF another method was called to merge multiple PDFs into one. This method should probably not have been called, but that's another story.

The bottom line is this method created a `new com.lowagie.text.Document()`, which by default creates an A4 sized document, and then was iterating over all pages of the pdf, adding the pages to the new document using `pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, currentPage++)`. These imported pages did not retain their original size.

I fixed it by passing the page size of the fist page when creating the merged document object:

```
document = new Document(pdfReader.getPageSize(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that you're (unwittingly) using software that is no longer supported. Anything that still has the namespace lowagie (the founder and CTO of iText) is really outdated.

If you simply want to convert HTML to pdf, why not use iText directly and cut out the middle-man?

We have multiple options for you.

1. XMLWorker (iText5 based code that converts HTML to pdf)
2. pdfHTML (iText7 based add-on that converts HTML5/CSS3 to pdf)

This is a rather extensive code-sample for using pdfHTML:

```
public void createPdf(String src, String dest, String resources) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);

        WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
        //Add metadata
        writerProperties.addXmpMetadata();

        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
        //Set the document to be tagged
        pdfDoc.setTagged();
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));

        //Set meta tags
        PdfDocumentInfo pdfMetaData = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
        pdfMetaData.setAuthor("Joris Schellekens");
        pdfMetaData.addCreationDate();
        pdfMetaData.getProducer();
        pdfMetaData.setCreator("iText Software");
        pdfMetaData.setKeywords("example, accessibility");
        pdfMetaData.setSubject("PDF accessibility");
        //Title is derived from html

        // pdf conversion
        ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider fp = new FontProvider();
        fp.addStandardPdfFonts();
        fp.addDirectory(resources);//The noto-nashk font file (.ttf extension) is placed in the resources

        props.setFontProvider(fp);
        props.setBaseUri(resources);
        //Setup custom tagworker factory for better tagging of headers
        DefaultTagWorkerFactory tagWorkerFactory = new AccessibilityTagWorkerFactory();
        props.setTagWorkerFactory(tagWorkerFactory);

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdfDoc, props);
        pdfDoc.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can find more information at http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm trying to fix an issue in an existing product, with minimal amount of changes. It would probably be more effort to upgrade to the latest itext. Out of curiosity though, would our 2.0.8 licence entitle us to an upgrade to the latest release?

Comment: I'm an iText developer. You'll have to take that up with sales.
They should be happy to help you out.